# location of mouse to draw a image

Tags: c#, cursor, panel, draw, point

here's code for interface of my project, but I can't determine location of mouse when I move mouse!when I draw image on screen, it not draw a right location!

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int _countRouter = 0;
    Point[] _posiRouter = new Point[100];
    readonly Image _imgRouter = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Router2.png");
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnRouter_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //panelMain.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);

        //Point x = Cursor.Position;
        Point x = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        if ((x.X > 10 || x.X < 660) && (x.Y > 30 || x.Y < 350))
        {
            _posiRouter[_countRouter].X = x.X;// -_imgRouter.Width;
            _posiRouter[_countRouter].Y = x.Y;// -_imgRouter.Height;
            _countRouter++;
        }
        this.panelOption.Invalidate();
        this.panelMain.Invalidate();
    }

    private void panelMain_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White,  
                        new Rectangle ( 0, 0, this.ClientRectangle.Width , 
                                        this.ClientRectangle.Height));

        for (int x = 0; x < _countRouter; x++)
        {
            g.DrawImage(_imgRouter, _posiRouter[x]);

        }
    }
// ... ?
}
```

Comment: not sure what your asking ... drawing, putting something when you click ... be more precise

Comment: please read my code! :)

Comment: I did ...  still not sure ... are you trying to draw a line of lets say up to 100 points?

Comment: No! I try drop a button a panel to a another panel! But location of it not right! :)

Comment: do you have any updates?

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The mouse coordinates vary based on the event being raised. For example, when the Control.MouseMove event is handled, the mouse coordinate values are relative to the coordinates of the control that raised the event. Some events related to drag-and-drop operations have associated mouse-coordinate values that are relative to the form origin or the screen origin.

Have a look there, and try to figure out what/where is your mouse by putting a debug point `Point x = new Point(e.X, e.Y);` to see what you get.